# Change samaccountname in .csv with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I need to compare enabled users in Active Directory with the user profile list from a server and then delete disabled profiles on the same server.

I'm trying to get a `.csv` list of users for each: one for the AD and one for the server.

When I get the server file, profiles are displayed like this: "domain\username" but with the AD file I only get: "username", so I can't compare them.

Ideally I would like to change the username when I get the AD file to add the domain. I tried to do something like this:

```
$Name = $_.SamAccountName
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' | select-object SamAccountName

    $Name = "DOMAIN\ + $Name"
}     
$users | Export-Csv c:\USEREnabled.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Which returns the .csv file with all SamAccountName but without any change done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a technique called "Calculated Properties". This is where we generate a new property for an object via `Select-Object`. Here's how it could work for you:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' | 
    Select-Object SamAccountName,@{Name='FullUserName';Expression={"YOURDOMAIN\$($_.SamAccountName)"}} |
    Export-CSV C:\Temp\UsersEnabled.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

This works by adding to `Select-Object` a hashtable with `Name` and `Expression` keys. Within the `Expression` key a scriptblock is used to build a new string that adds Domain to the SamAccountName property of each user in the pipeline (which is represented by the automatic variable `$_`).

The result of this will be an object with two properties returned: SamAccountName and FullUserName.

Comment: This will work just fine if you always know the domain. But AD does actually have a constructed attribute with the DOMAIN\username: `msDS-PrincipalName`. So you could do something like this: `Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties sAMAccountName,msDS-PrincipalName | Select-Object SamAccountName,msDS-PrincipalName`